# Parsing a date string using java.text.SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, datetime, formatting, iso8601

I have a weird problem, I need to parse a date string that looks like `1997-02-14T00:00:00.0000000+05:30`. The odd thing about the date string is the time zone information. It's `+05:30` instead of the usual `+0530`.

I have the basic format string ready, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ` which would have worked like a charm, if not for the TZ information.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem? Is there some kind format string which can handle that kind of TZ info?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Contrary to your second sentence, `+05:30` is *not* a time zone. That text is an offset from UTC. A time zone has a name in format of `Continent/Region` such as `Europe/Paris` or `Asia/Kolkata`.

Comment: There is nothing odd about `+05:30` with a COLON character (`:`) versus `+0530`. Quite the opposite, as I have seen multiple libraries that expect the COLON character to be present despite the international standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) making it optional. So I recommend always including the COLON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not preprocess with a regex and replace the timezone e.g.

```
String dateAndTime = ...
String preprocessed = dateAndTime.replace("([+-])(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)$", "$1$2$3");
// Go on with your life
```

Answer (score 5):

I've looked into this problem myself several month ago. If I remember correctly, SimpleDateFormat isn't flexible enough to accept other timezone formats (mine was +530). What I did was a simple pre-processing step - i.e. try to remove the colon before passing the String to SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 3):

### Java 8+

The most appropriate type to prase *1997-02-14T00:00:00.0000000+05:30* into is [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html). Note that `java.time` API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and therefore you do not need to specify a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse a date-time string which is already in ISO 8601 format.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "1997-02-14T00:00:00.0000000+05:30";
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(odt);

        // Technically, you can also parse it into a ZonedDateTime but a ZonedDateTime
        // is supposed to contain ZoneId along with ZoneOffset
        System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime));

        // With Java 12+, it is also possible to parse it into an Instant
        System.out.println(Instant.parse(strDateTime));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
1997-02-14T00:00+05:30
1997-02-14T00:00+05:30
1997-02-13T18:30:00Z
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### Just for the sake of completeness

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. Since the release of Java-8 (Mar 2014), it is highly recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html). However, for any reason, if you want to stick to the legacy API, you can use `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSXXX")` to parse your string.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String strDateTime = "1997-02-14T00:00:00.0000000+05:30";
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSXXX");
        Date date = sdf.parse(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Thu Feb 13 18:30:00 GMT 1997
```

Answer (score 2):

SimpleDateFormat should accept this. From [the doc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone):

> For parsing, general time zones are
>   also accepted.

and these [are specified as](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone):

```
GMTOffsetTimeZone:
             GMT Sign Hours : Minutes
```

which looks like what you have ?

If that fails, then the [Joda DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) claims to do this. I would be tempted to use Joda regardless, for a whole range of reasons (a more consistent and simpler API, thread-safety for formatters/parsers etc.)

Comment: I've just tested it, but it doesn't work: new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z").parse("Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -07:00")

Comment: What happens if (say) you have GMT-07:00 (I appreciate that's not what you currently have)

Comment: Yes, it works after prepending GMT to the timezone ("Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 GMT-07:00"). But given the format from the question, this (using 'z' instead of 'Z' in format string) still isn't a viable way to parse those dates.

Comment: Yes. Agreed. You may want to check out Joda (for this and other time/date issues)

Answer (score 2):

Is this by chance a date string that comes from an XML file (ISO8601 format)? Unfortunately there is no (easy) way to parse this with `SimpleDateFormat`, exactly due to the ':' in the timezone part that `SimpleDateFormat` has no way to deal with properly.

Have a look at [my answer in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553695/how-to-interpret-the-these-time-stamps/1553983#1553983) about how to parse XML datetime strings.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, there is always the hack of **preprocessing your String**.

If nobody finds a better answer, that would be something already. You could encapsulate it in a method, with a comment to explain the hack.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should use the `replaceAll` method of the `String` for `regular expression`.

```
String dateAndTime = ...
String preprocessed = dateAndTime.replaceAll("(GMT)([+-])(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)", "$2$3$4");
```