# Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, iso8601

I am trying to convert an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted String to a `java.util.Date`.

I found the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` to be ISO8601-compliant if used with a Locale (compare sample).

However, using the `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, I cannot convert the correctly formatted String `2010-01-01T12:00:00+01:00`. I have to convert it first to `2010-01-01T12:00:00+0100`, without the colon.

So, the current solution is

```java
SimpleDateFormat ISO8601DATEFORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.GERMANY);
String date = "2010-01-01T12:00:00+01:00".replaceAll("\\+0([0-9]){1}\\:00", "+0$100");
System.out.println(ISO8601DATEFORMAT.parse(date));
```

which obviously isn't that nice. Am I missing something or is there a better solution?

---

**Answer**

Thanks to JuanZe's comment, I found the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) magic, it is also [described here](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/java/date-time-parsing-formatting-joda-time.html).

So, the solution is

```java
DateTimeFormatter parser2 = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();
String jtdate = "2010-01-01T12:00:00+01:00";
System.out.println(parser2.parseDateTime(jtdate));
```

Or more simply, use the default parser via the constructor:

```java
DateTime dt = new DateTime( "2010-01-01T12:00:00+01:00" ) ;
```

To me, this is nice.

Comment: Be ready to receive a lot of "Use JodaTime" answers...

Comment: @Ice09: If the API documentation for DateTimeFormat is correct (the JoDa documentation can be misleading, wrong or incomplete though), the pattern you've used in your own "answer" is not compatible with ISO8601.

Comment: @jarnbjo: thanks for the comment - you might be right, I looked it up again and came up with the much better solution ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis(), which kind of guarantees that the correct format is used.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554852/parsing-a-date-string-using-java-text-simpledateformat and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580925/simpledateformat-parsing and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013681/parse-this-type-of-date-format-in-java-date-with-z-literal and

Comment: I'm not sure when this was added, but the 'X' appears to solve this problem within SimpleDateFormat. The pattern "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX" successfully parses the example in the question.

Comment: The 'X' is available since Java 7.

Comment: [Apache Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org) uses the ISO 8601 format for persisting dates, and there is a helper class to parse them: [org.apache.jackrabbit.util.ISO8601](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jackrabbit/trunk/jackrabbit-jcr-commons/src/main/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/util/ISO8601.java) Comes with [jackrabbit-jcr-commons](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jackrabbit/jackrabbit-jcr-commons).

Comment: The embedded answer with [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) can be much shorter, a single line of code, no need to call parse method: `new DateTime( "2010-01-01T12:00:00+01:00" )`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20578792/642706) for details.

Comment: I found an answer that worked for me on [this particular answer][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10615059/2413303

Comment: Java 8 makes it easy! There is a hidden gem by Adam in the answers below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27479533/1262901

Comment: Joda DateTime didn't support 20190531T194819Z(yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssSSS'Z') example from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 and hence added the solution below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date/56400421#56400421

Comment: what is the format of 2023-06-12T10:49:010Z, can someone help on this

Answer (score 514, accepted):

Unfortunately, the time zone formats available to [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (Java 6 and earlier) are not [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant. SimpleDateFormat understands time zone strings like "GMT+01:00" or "+0100", the latter according to [RFC # 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt).

Even if Java 7 added support for time zone descriptors according to ISO 8601, SimpleDateFormat is still not able to properly parse a complete date string, as it has no support for optional parts.

Reformatting your input string using regexp is certainly one possibility, but the replacement rules are not as simple as in your question:

- Some time zones are not full hours off [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), so the string does not necessarily end with ":00".
- ISO8601 allows only the number of hours to be included in the time zone, so "+01" is equivalent to "+01:00"
- ISO8601 allows the usage of "Z" to indicate UTC instead of "+00:00".

The easier solution is possibly to use the data type converter in JAXB, since JAXB must be able to parse ISO8601 date string according to the XML Schema specification. `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("2010-01-01T12:00:00Z")` will give you a `Calendar` object and you can simply use getTime() on it, if you need a `Date` object.

You could probably use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) as well, but I don't know why you should bother with that (Update 2022; maybe because the entire `javax.xml.bind` section is missing from Android's `javax.xml` package).

Comment: The JAXB-solution is a really creative approach! It works as well, I have tested it with my sample. However, for whoever faces the problem and is allowed to use JodaTime, I would advise to use it, since it feels more natural. But your solution requires not additional libraries (at least with Java 6).

Comment: Here's the reverse: Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();c.setTime(aDate);return javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDateTime(c);

Comment: Wow, that's a really non-obvious place to put such a useful thing.  Been searching for a few days.

Comment: Actually it's not so simple b/c you have to initialize the jaxb datatypeConverter.  I ended up using DatatypeFactory myself as DataTypeConverterImpl did internally.  What a headache.

Comment: If that's all true, you should update Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators as it indicates that you are (at least partially) incorrect.

Answer (score 322):

The way that is [blessed by Java 7 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
String string1 = "2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700";
Date result1 = df1.parse(string1);

DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
String string2 = "2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00";
Date result2 = df2.parse(string2);
```

You can find more examples in section *Examples* at [SimpleDateFormat javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

**UPD 02/13/2020:** There is a [completely new way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60214805/203204) to do this in Java 8

Comment: Your answer helped me to convert MongoDB's ISODate to local date. Regards.

Comment: this is valid as of java 7

Comment: @b.long Java added more than a constant for such ISO 8601 compliant formats. Java got an entire new framework for date-time work that includes built-in default support for such formats. See the new [`java.time` framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8, inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), supplanting the troublesome java.util.Date, .Calendar, and SimpleDateFormat classes.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @BasilBourque.  I should say, I'm glad there's a Java 7 solution to this that the community has accepted.

Comment: Also this works better than javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDateTime(c) because it doesn't truncate the fractional seconds if milliseconds is 0.

Comment: Doesn't this mean you need to know the date format in advance? What if you have to accept `string1` and `string2` but don't know which you will get.

Comment: 'Z' needs to be in quotes

Comment: @kervin If the Z is in quotes, won't the formatter be looking specifically for the character Z, not all of the offset strings it can represent? It seems like quoting Z would only work by coincidence, if your date strings happened to be in UTC.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is not the approved answer to this post instead of the one from 2010 by @jarnbjo

Comment: well this is worked for my case. `SimpleDateFormat` + `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX` is enough before we migrate to OffsetDateTime (Java 8 API)

Comment: it solved my 3 days of work just in a moment

Comment: @spaaarky21 If you read accepted answer: "`ISO8601 allows the usage of "Z" to indicate UTC instead of "+00:00"`", hence if input is UTC, the Z should be quoted with single-quotes.

Comment: Yes, ISO 8601 define Z as shorthand for +00:00. But there is a difference between a format string that is simply looking for the string "Z" without any regard for what it *represents*, and the parser/formatter's Z **pattern**, which handles the wide variety of ways offset can be represented.

Answer (score 210):

Okay, this question is already answered, but I'll drop my answer anyway. It might help someone.

I've been looking for a **solution for Android** (API 7).

- Joda was out of the question - it is huge and suffers from slow initialization. It also seemed a major overkill for that particular purpose.
- Answers involving `javax.xml` won't work on Android API 7.

Ended up implementing this simple class. It covers **only the most common form** of ISO 8601 strings, but this should be enough in some cases (when you're quite sure that the input will be in *this* format).

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

/**
 * Helper class for handling a most common subset of ISO 8601 strings
 * (in the following format: "2008-03-01T13:00:00+01:00"). It supports
 * parsing the "Z" timezone, but many other less-used features are
 * missing.
 */
public final class ISO8601 {
    /** Transform Calendar to ISO 8601 string. */
    public static String fromCalendar(final Calendar calendar) {
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        String formatted = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
            .format(date);
        return formatted.substring(0, 22) + ":" + formatted.substring(22);
    }

    /** Get current date and time formatted as ISO 8601 string. */
    public static String now() {
        return fromCalendar(GregorianCalendar.getInstance());
    }

    /** Transform ISO 8601 string to Calendar. */
    public static Calendar toCalendar(final String iso8601string)
            throws ParseException {
        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        String s = iso8601string.replace("Z", "+00:00");
        try {
            s = s.substring(0, 22) + s.substring(23);  // to get rid of the ":"
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            throw new ParseException("Invalid length", 0);
        }
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").parse(s);
        calendar.setTime(date);
        return calendar;
    }
}
```

**Performance note:** I instantiate new SimpleDateFormat every time as means to avoid [a bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8258) in Android 2.1. If you're as astonished as I was, see [this riddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624752/simpledateformat-timezone-bug-on-android). For other Java engines, you may cache the instance in a private static field (using ThreadLocal, to be thread safe).

Comment: Perhaps this should have been made into a question of its own, with its own answer?

Comment: This was the first page I've stubled upon when I was looking for the answer, so it seemed fit. For most Java developers, Android is not exactly Java. However, in most cases, one works the same as the other, so many Android developers will search for "java" when looking for this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31198/discussion-between-marcus-junius-brutus-and-wrygiel)

Comment: i had to add .SSS for fractional seconds but works great thx. Why do you do `s = s.substring(0, 22) + s.substring(23);` - i dont see the point in this

Answer (score 153):

### java.time

The [java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (built into Java 8 and later), makes this a little easier.

If you know the input is in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), such as the `Z` (for Zulu) on the end, the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class can parse.

```java
Date date = Date.from(Instant.parse("2014-12-12T10:39:40Z"));
```

If your input may be another [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) values rather than [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) indicated by the `Z` (Zulu) on the end, use the [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class to parse.

```java
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2010-01-01T12:00:00+01:00");
```

Then extract an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), and  convert to a [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) by calling [`from`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from).

```java
Instant instant = odt.toInstant(); // Instant is always in UTC.
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

Comment: This answer is working too hard. A java.util.Date by definition has no time zone. So no need for all that time zone related code: the `LocalDateTime` and `ZoneId` and `atZone`. This simple one-liner will do: `java.util.Date date = Date.from( ZonedDateTime.parse( "2014-12-12T10:39:40Z" ).toInstant() );`

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks, I knew going via LocalDateTime was wrong but couldn't find the quick way, answer updated.

Comment: @BasilBourque This is unnecessarily complicated: `Date.from(Instant.parse("2014-12-12T10:39:40Z" ));` is enough.

Comment: @assylias you are correct but that will only work when the date string is UTC zone, ISO8601 allows any timezone...

Comment: @Adam My bad - I hadn't realised the question was more general than your example. As a side comment an `OffsetDateTime` would be enough to parse ISO8601 (which does not contain time zone information but only an offset).

Comment: @assylias Thanks for your comment about letting `Instant` do the parsing. While not sufficient for this particular Question, it is an important distinction worth pointing out. So I added a second example of code. Oops, just noticed this is not originally my Answer; I hope Adam approves.

Comment: @BasilBourque yes I was planning to update answer in a similar way,  you've saved me a job,  thanks

Comment: You have saved a lot of time, appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 82):

Starting from Java 8, there is a completely new officially supported way to do this:

```
    String s = "2020-02-13T18:51:09.840Z";
    TemporalAccessor ta = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.parse(s);
    Instant i = Instant.from(ta);
    Date d = Date.from(i);
```

Comment: If the string is in the instant format, with trailing `Z` as offset, we don’t need to specify this explicitly. Just `Instant i = Instant.parse(s);`. The string in the question had `+01:00`, in which case `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT` does not work (at least not on my Java 11).

Comment: @OleV.V. You can use `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` to format dates with offsets, like `+01:00` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#predefined)

Comment: That’s true, @LucasBasquerotto. Though not mentioning that formatter explicitly, the answers [by Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27479533/5772882) and [by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20578792/5772882) already do something similar.

Comment: This cannot parse "2020-06-01T14:34:00-05:00" which is a string produced by Javascript's toISOString() method.

Answer (score 76):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse ( "2010-01-01T12:00:00+01:00" )
```

Or for Java 12+, use `Instant.parse` as seen in the [Answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74256999/642706).

## Using java.time

The new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package in Java 8 and later was inspired by Joda-Time.

The `OffsetDateTime` class represents a moment on the timeline with an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) but not a time zone.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse ( "2010-01-01T12:00:00+01:00" );
```

Calling `toString` generates a string in standard ISO 8601 format:

> 2010-01-01T12:00+01:00

To see the same value through the lens of UTC, extract an `Instant` or adjust the offset from `+01:00` to `00:00`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant();
```

…or…

```
OffsetDateTime odtUtc = odt.withOffsetSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

Adjust into a time zone if desired. A [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is a history of [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) values for a region, with a set of rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). So apply a time zone rather than a mere offset whenever possible.

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeMontréal = odt.atZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

For a date-only value, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2010 , Month.JANUARY , 1 ) ;
```

Or:

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2010-01-01" ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

---

Comment: I don't think this is helpful, as it does not parse ISO 8601 dates, only a very specific subset. For example, `java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse ( "2010-01-01" )` fails

Comment: @phil294 All of the *java.time* classes parse ISO 8601 standard format inputs as appropriate to each class. Your example of `"2010-01-01"` is a date alone, so will be parsed by the date-only class, `LocalDate`. Ex: `LocalDate.parse( "2010-01-01" )`. Your example class of `OffsetDateTime` is for a date, with a time-of-day, with an offset (a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead/behind UTC). So `OffsetDateTime` parses ISO 8601 formatted inputs with a date, a time, and an offset. Ex: `OffsetDateTime.parse( "2010-01-01T12:30:00-08:00" )`. [Run code live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/SiqcZl).

Answer (score 74):

The [Jackson-databind library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) also has [ISO8601DateFormat class](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/ISO8601DateFormat.java) that does that (actual implementation in [ISO8601Utils](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/ISO8601Utils.java).

```
ISO8601DateFormat df = new ISO8601DateFormat();
Date d = df.parse("2010-07-28T22:25:51Z");
```

Comment: It fails to parse this date: `2015-08-11T13:10:00`. I get `String index out of range: 19`. Looking at the code it seems that it requires the milliseconds to be specified, and the timezone. Those should be optional.

Comment: To quote the documentation, the parse format is: `[yyyy-MM-dd|yyyyMMdd][T(hh:mm[:ss[.sss]]|hhmm[ss[.sss]])]?[Z|[+-]hh:mm]]`.

In other words, the milliseconds is optional but the timezone is mandatory.

Comment: Ah yes actually it looks like you are right. Still, I'm pretty sure ISO8601 allows you to omit the timezone so it's still wrong. JodaTime works though: `new DateTime("2015-08-11T13:10:00").toDate()`

Comment: That class is now deprecated, the new one is StdDateFormat. Otherwise it works the same.

Comment: ISO8601DateFormat is deprecated use StdDateFormat instead

Answer (score 35):

For Java version 7

You can follow Oracle documentation: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

X - is used for ISO 8601 time zone

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
df.setTimeZone(tz);
String nowAsISO = df.format(new Date());

System.out.println(nowAsISO);

DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
//nowAsISO = "2013-05-31T00:00:00Z";
Date finalResult = df1.parse(nowAsISO);

System.out.println(finalResult);
```

Comment: This means the timezone is *required*. According to ISO 8601 it is optional. As are the seconds, etc. So this only parses a specific subset of ISO 8601.

Comment: Works great with Java 1.8

Answer (score 23):

The DatatypeConverter solution doesn't work in all VMs. The following works for me:

```
javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2011-01-01Z").toGregorianCalendar().getTime()
```

I've found that joda does not work out of the box (specifically for the example I gave above with the timezone on a date, which should be valid)

Answer (score 17):

I think we should use

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
```

for Date `2010-01-01T12:00:00Z`

Comment: Why is this a better answer than the others, included the accepted answer with 76 upvotes?

Comment: @ErickRobertson: It is simple, out of the box, flexible, no conversions, and most people don't care about time zones.

Comment: not much point working with times if you dont care about timezones!

Comment: This **IGNORES** the timezone completely. Was using this until I realized this was happening, so I switched to JodaTime.

Comment: Throwing away the time zone will simply result in errors at some point.

Comment: -1. This just adds a 'Z' (literal) to the format but doesn't really take timezone into account .. as others have pointed out already. Don't use!

Comment: This is quite dangerous actually. By appending a Z to the string you're saying it's a UTC time (0 offset). Please consider removing our answer.

Comment: If your application follows the convention of always producing UTC dates then this is fine for reproducing dates. The only risk is that somehow non-UTC dates end op in your database and get blindly produced as if they were UTC. For dates received from clients this will only work if they send UTC dates with the 'Z' (not +00:00) notation. Dates with non-UTC timezones or different format will not be parsed correctly by this formatter.

Comment: A warning should be added to this solution as to not misguide people: Unless this is running in a UTC timezone it will produce incorrect results.

Comment: It should be `X`, or `XX`, or `XXX`, for zoned string `+02`, `+0200`, and `+02:00`, respectively. In this way, it takes timezone into consideration.

Answer (score 11):

After I searched a lot to convert ISO8601 to date I suddenly found a java class that is *ISO8601Util.java* and this was part of *com.google.gson.internal.bind.util*.
So you can use it to convert dates.

```
ISO8601Utils.parse("2010-01-01T12:00:00Z" , ParsePosition(0))
```

and you can simply use this kotlin extension function

```
fun String.getDateFromString() : Date? = ISO8601Utils.parse(this , 
ParsePosition(0))
```

Comment: Seems like this is deprecated in jackson now

Comment: Tnx I will check it out

Comment: In version 2.8.6 this doesn't work with some ISO8601 formats, e.g.  2021-04-16T04:28:27.792909 or 2021-04-16T04:28:27.792909+15:0

Comment: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/ISO8601Utils.html
check out this documentation

Comment: As the package name suggests, this is an *internal* class of Gson so you should not use it. If possible use one of the alternatives mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 10):

Another very simple way to parse ISO8601 timestamps is to use  `org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils`:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ISO8601TimestampFormatTest {
  @Test
  public void parse() throws ParseException {
    Date date = DateUtils.parseDate("2010-01-01T12:00:00+01:00", new String[]{ "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ" });
    assertEquals("Fri Jan 01 12:00:00 CET 2010", date.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The workaround for Java 7+ is using SimpleDateFormat:
`DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", Locale.US);`

This code can parse ISO8601 format like:

- `2017-05-17T06:01:43.785Z`
- `2017-05-13T02:58:21.391+01:00`

But on Java6, `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't understand `X` character and will throw
`IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'`
We need to normalize ISO8601 date to the format readable in Java 6 with `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
public static Date iso8601Format(String formattedDate) throws ParseException {
    try {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", Locale.US);
        return df.parse(formattedDate);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        // error happen in Java 6: Unknown pattern character 'X'
        if (formattedDate.endsWith("Z")) formattedDate = formattedDate.replace("Z", "+0000");
        else formattedDate = formattedDate.replaceAll("([+-]\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)\\s*$", "$1$2");
        DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.US);
        return df1.parse(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

Method above to replace [`Z` with `+0000`] or [`+01:00` with `+0100`] when error occurs in Java 6 (you can detect Java version and replace try/catch with if statement).

Comment: No, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are poorly designed, confusing, and flawed. They are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes built into Java 8 and later. For Java 6 and Java 7, much of the java.time functionality is back-ported in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Much better to add that library to your app than use those legacy classes. One-line solution in java.time: `OffsetDateTime.parse( "2010-01-01T12:00:00+01:00" )`

Answer (score 8):

**Java 8+**

Simple one liner that I didn't found in answers:

```
Date date = Date.from(ZonedDateTime.parse("2010-01-01T12:00:00+01:00").toInstant());
```

Date doesn't contain timezone, it will be stored in UTC, but will be properly converted to your JVM timezone even during simple output with `System.out.println(date)`.

Comment: I think you’re right, it’s not exactly in the other answers. It’s still better if one can avoid `Date` completely since that class is poorly designed and long outdated. It’s better to use `ZonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant()` for converting to one’s own time zone, for example. Only use this answer if you necessarily need a `Date` for a legacy API that you cannot afford to upgrade to java.time just now.

Answer (score 7):

Java has a dozen different ways to parse a date-time, as the excellent answers here demonstrate. But somewhat amazingly, none of Java's time classes fully implement ISO 8601!

With Java 8, I'd recommend:

```
ZonedDateTime zp = ZonedDateTime.parse(string);
Date date = Date.from(zp.toInstant());
```

That will handle examples both in UTC and with an offset, like "2017-09-13T10:36:40Z" or "2017-09-13T10:36:40+01:00". It will do for most use cases.

But it won't handle examples like "2017-09-13T10:36:40+01", which *is* a valid ISO 8601 date-time.
It also won't handle date only, e.g. "2017-09-13".

If you have to handle those, I'd suggest using a regex first to sniff the syntax.

There's a nice list of ISO 8601 examples here with lots of corner cases: https://www.myintervals.com/blog/2009/05/20/iso-8601-date-validation-that-doesnt-suck/ I'm not aware of any Java class that could cope with all of them.

Comment: `OffsetDateTime` will do and conceptually matches a date-time with an offset better.

Comment: Hey @OleV.V. thanks for the suggestion. Sadly no: OffsetDateTime.parse() will throw an exception for several valid ISO 8601 strings, e.g. "2017-09-13T10:36:40+01" or "2017-09-13"

Comment: I only meant to say that `OffsetDateTime` handles the examples that you handle with `ZonedDateTime`. I believe that it doesn’t handle any of the examples that `ZonedDateTime` doesn’t. In that sense it’s no improvement (but also no worse). Sorry, I wasn’t perfectly clear.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in 2020, given the state of things.

Answer (score 6):

## java.time

Note that in Java 8, you can use the [java.time.ZonedDateTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class and its static `parse(CharSequence text)` method.

Comment: The input strings in the Question have only an offset-from-UTC, not a full time zone. So `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` are appropriate here, not `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 6):

I faced the **same** problem and solved it by the following code .

```
 public static Calendar getCalendarFromISO(String datestring) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault()) ;
    SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        Date date = dateformat.parse(datestring);
        date.setHours(date.getHours() - 1);
        calendar.setTime(date);

        String test = dateformat.format(calendar.getTime());
        Log.e("TEST_TIME", test);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return calendar;
}
```

Earlier I was using
`SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.getDefault());`

But later i found the main cause of the exception was the `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` ,

So i used

`SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault());`

It worked fine for me .

Comment: Just what I needed without having to use joda-time, XML api or anything else. Just the correct pattern.

Answer (score 5):

Also you can use the following class -

```
org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.ISO8601DateFormat


Date date = ISO8601DateFormat.parse("date in iso8601");
```

Link to the Java Doc - [Hierarchy For Package org.springframework.extensions.surf.maven.plugin.util](http://www.springsurf.org/sites/1.0.0.M3/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/extensions/surf/maven/plugin/util/package-tree.html)

Comment: deprecated: Use com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.StdDateFormat instead

Answer (score 5):

## Java 12

Since Java 12, [`Instant#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) can parse a date-time string containing time-zone offset.

```
Date dt = Date.from(Instant.parse(your-date-time-string));
```

Parse your [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted date-time strings using [`Instant#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) and convert the result into `java.util.Date` using [`Date#from`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#from(java.time.Instant)). See this code [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/a7iuXF).

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream.of(
        "2010-01-01T12:00:00+01:00",
        "2010-01-01T12:00:00-01:00",
        "2010-01-01T12:00:00Z"
      )
      .map(Instant::parse)
      .map(Date::from)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

See this code [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/6zJV4P).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: If one indispensably needs an old-fashioned `Date` for a legacy API, this is the modern and elegant solution. I can’t remember exactly from which Java version `Instant.parse("2010-01-01T12:00:00+01:00")` works with an offset other than `Z`?

Comment: I suggest changing your heading from "TL;DR"  to `Instant.parse`

Comment: @OleV.V. The Javadoc for [`Instant.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) for Java 17 & 19 still says the input must be in UTC. To quote: "The string must represent a valid instant in UTC". However, the Javadoc for [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT) says it will "parse the offset, converting the instant to UTC". Seems Java 12 is the first Javadoc for `ISO_INSTANT` to mention parsing the offset.

Comment: Thanks, @BasilBourque. Java 12 it is. Trying the code in Java 11 I do get `Text '2010-01-01T12:00:00+01:00' could not be parsed at index 19`. The ideone link demonstrates that it does work in Java 12.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned Android does not have a good way to support parsing/formatting ISO 8601 dates using classes included in the SDK.  I have written this code multiple times so I finally created a Gist that includes a DateUtils class that supports formatting and parsing ISO 8601 and RFC 1123 dates.  The Gist also includes a test case showing what it supports.

https://gist.github.com/mraccola/702330625fad8eebe7d3

Answer (score 2):

SimpleDateFormat for JAVA 1.7 has a cool pattern for ISO 8601 format.

[Class SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone)

Here is what I did:

```
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
         Locale.ENGLISH).format(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: `Z` in format string is not ISO 8601 time zone, you should use `X` (or `XX` or `XXX`) if you want ISO 8601 time zone

Comment: d  is of type String

Answer (score 2):

Use string like 
`LocalDate.parse(((String) data.get("d_iso8601")),DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE)`

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised that not even one java library supports all ISO 8601 date formats as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601. Joda DateTime was supporting most of them, but not all and hence I added custom logic to handle all of them. Here is my implementation.

```html
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class ISO8601DateUtils {
 
 /**
  * It parses all the date time formats from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 and returns Joda DateTime.
  * Zoda DateTime does not support dates of format 20190531T160233Z, and hence added custom logic to handle this using SimpleDateFormat.
  * @param dateTimeString ISO 8601 date time string
  * @return
  */
 public static DateTime parse(String dateTimeString) {
  try {
   return new DateTime( dateTimeString );
  } catch(Exception e) {
   try {
    Date dateTime = DateUtils.parseDate(dateTimeString, JODA_NOT_SUPPORTED_ISO_DATES);
    return new DateTime(dateTime.getTime());
   } catch (ParseException e1) {
    throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Date %s could not be parsed to ISO date", dateTimeString));
   }
  }
 }
  
   private static String[] JODA_NOT_SUPPORTED_ISO_DATES = new String[] {
   // upto millis
   "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssSSS'Z'",
   "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssSSSZ",
   "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssSSSXXX",
   
   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmssSSS'Z'",
   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmssSSSZ",
   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmssSSSXXX",
   
   // upto seconds
   "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'",
   "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ",
   "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssXXX",
   
   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmss'Z'", 
   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmssZ",
   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmssXXX",
   
   // upto minutes
   "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmm'Z'",
   "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmZ",
   "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmXXX",

   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmm'Z'",
   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmZ",
   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmXXX",
   
   //upto hours is already supported by Joda DateTime
 };
}
```

Comment: Half of those are not valid ISO-8601 date/times.  From wikipedia: `Either basic or extended formats may be used, but both date and time must use the same format`

Answer (score 2):

When want to convert from UTC to format that we want. It will change depend on the zone/location we stay

```
//utcDate = "2021-06-05T02:46:29Z"
fun converterUtcToReadableDateTime(utcDate: String): String {
    val offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.parse(utcDate), ZoneId.systemDefault())
    val patternDate = "dd MMM yyyy h:mm a"
    return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(patternDate).format(offsetDateTime)
}

fun converterUtcToReadableDate(utcDate: String): String {
    val offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.parse(utcDate), ZoneId.systemDefault())
    val patternDate = "d MMM yyyy"
    return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(patternDate).format(offsetDateTime)
}

fun converterUtcToReadableTime(utcDate: String): String {
    val offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.parse(utcDate), ZoneId.systemDefault())
    val patternDate = "h:mm a"
    return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(patternDate).format(offsetDateTime)
}
```

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is exactly the wrong class to use here. You are throwing away vital information, offset-from-UTC, without anything gained.

Comment: @OleV.V. yes thank you for the correction

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68258560/9346054 I think best one for custom, not using instant UTC

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    String dateStr = "2016-10-19T14:15:36+08:00";
    Date date = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(dateStr).getTime();

    System.out.println(date);

}
```

Here is the output:

Wed Oct 19 15:15:36 CST 2016

Answer (score 1):

A little test that shows how to parse a date in ISO8601 and that LocalDateTime does not handle DSTs.

```
 @Test
    public void shouldHandleDaylightSavingTimes() throws ParseException {

        //ISO8601 UTC date format
        SimpleDateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");

        // 1 hour of difference between 2 dates in UTC happening at the Daylight Saving Time
        Date d1 = utcFormat.parse("2019-10-27T00:30:00.000Z");
        Date d2 = utcFormat.parse("2019-10-27T01:30:00.000Z");

        //Date 2 is before date 2
        Assert.assertTrue(d1.getTime() < d2.getTime());
        // And there is 1 hour difference between the 2 dates
        Assert.assertEquals(1000*60*60, d2.getTime() - d1.getTime());

        //Print the dates in local time
        SimpleDateFormat localFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm z Z", Locale.forLanguageTag("fr_CH"));
        localFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Zurich"));

        //Both dates are at 02h30 local time (because of DST), but one is CEST +0200 and the other CET +0100 (clock goes backwards)
        Assert.assertEquals("2019-10-27 02:30 CEST +0200", localFormat.format(d1));
        Assert.assertEquals("2019-10-27 02:30 CET +0100", localFormat.format(d2));

        //Small test that shows that LocalDateTime does not handle DST (and should not be used for storing timeseries data)
        LocalDateTime ld1 = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(d1.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("Europe/Zurich"));
        LocalDateTime ld2 = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(d2.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("Europe/Zurich"));

        //Note that a localdatetime does not handle DST, therefore the 2 dates are the same
        Assert.assertEquals(ld1, ld2);

        //They both have the following local values
        Assert.assertEquals(2019, ld1.getYear());
        Assert.assertEquals(27, ld1.getDayOfMonth());
        Assert.assertEquals(10, ld1.getMonthValue());
        Assert.assertEquals(2, ld1.getHour());
        Assert.assertEquals(30, ld1.getMinute());
        Assert.assertEquals(0, ld1.getSecond());

    }
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: You are correct that `LocalDateTime` doesn’t handle summer time (DST) since it doesn’t handle a time zone at all. For that we need `ZonedDateTime`. Proposing `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` is — IMHO bad.

Comment: Indeed ZonedDateTime works. And java.time.Instant is also a good alternative to handle DST. I know that java.util.Date is deprecated and should not be used, but I was just answering the original question: How to convert a String in 8601 to java.util.date....

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need: I needed to be able to parse any date ISO8601 compliant without knowing the exact format in advance, and I wanted a lightweight solution which would also work on Android.

When I googled my needs I stumbled upon this question, and noticed that AFAIU, no answer completely fit my needs. So I developed [jISO8601](https://github.com/gturri/jISO8601)  and pushed it on maven central.

Just add in you `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>fr.turri</groupId>
  <artifactId>jISO8601</artifactId>
  <version>0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and then you're good to go:

```
import fr.turri.jiso8601.*;
...
Calendar cal = Iso8601Deserializer.toCalendar("1985-03-04");
Date date = Iso8601Deserializer.toDate("1985-03-04T12:34:56Z");
```

Hopes it help.

Answer (score 0):

To just format a date like this the following worked for me in a Java 6 based application. There is a `DateFormat` class `JacksonThymeleafISO8601DateFormat` in the thymeleaf project which inserts the missing colon:

https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/blob/40d27f44df7b52eda47d1bc6f1b3012add6098b3/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/standard/serializer/StandardJavaScriptSerializer.java

I used it for ECMAScript date format compatibilty.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't use Java 8 features, so only `java.util.Date` was available. I already had a dependency on gson library but didn't want to use `ISO8601Utils` directly. `ISO8601Utils` is an internal API, [gson's authors warns not to use it](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/package-info.java).

I parsed a ISO8601 date using gson's public API:

```
fun parseISO8601DateToLocalTimeOrNull(date: String): Date? {
    return try {
        GsonBuilder()
            .create()
            .getAdapter(Date::class.java)
            .fromJson("\"$date\"")
     } catch (t: Throwable) {
        null
     }
}
```

Under the hood, the adapter still uses `ISO8601Utils`. But if you're using the adapter you can be sure that a different compatible version of gson won't break your project.

I worried that creation of adapter may be slow so I measured execution time on Pixel 3a with `debuggable=false`.`parseISO8601DateToLocalTimeOrNull` took ~0.5 milliseconds to parse a date.

Comment: I wonder what on Earth would keep you from using Java 8 features? An evil boss forcing you to use Java 5??

Comment: I develop an SDK that targets Android API 21+. Java8 classes on Android have been available since API 24. As an SDK developer, I don't want to bring new dependencies like ThreeTenABP nor force SDK users to turn on desugaring in their applications. So I decided to suffer with `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score -1):

Base Function Courtesy : @wrygiel.

This function can convert ISO8601 format to Java Date which can handle the offset values. As per the [definition of ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC) the offset can be mentioned in different formats.

```
±[hh]:[mm]
±[hh][mm]
±[hh]

Eg:  "18:30Z", "22:30+04", "1130-0700", and "15:00-03:30" all mean the same time. - 06:30PM UTC
```

This class has static methods to convert

- ISO8601 string to Date(Local TimeZone) object
- Date to ISO8601 string
- Daylight Saving is automatically calc

Sample ISO8601 Strings

```
/*       "2013-06-25T14:00:00Z";
         "2013-06-25T140000Z";
         "2013-06-25T14:00:00+04";
         "2013-06-25T14:00:00+0400";
         "2013-06-25T140000+0400";
         "2013-06-25T14:00:00-04";
         "2013-06-25T14:00:00-0400";
         "2013-06-25T140000-0400";*/


public class ISO8601DateFormatter {

private static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT_1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
private static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT_2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmssZ");
private static final String UTC_PLUS = "+";
private static final String UTC_MINUS = "-";

public static Date toDate(String iso8601string) throws ParseException {
    iso8601string = iso8601string.trim();
    if(iso8601string.toUpperCase().indexOf("Z")>0){
        iso8601string = iso8601string.toUpperCase().replace("Z", "+0000");
    }else if(((iso8601string.indexOf(UTC_PLUS))>0)){
        iso8601string = replaceColon(iso8601string, iso8601string.indexOf(UTC_PLUS));
        iso8601string = appendZeros(iso8601string, iso8601string.indexOf(UTC_PLUS), UTC_PLUS);
    }else if(((iso8601string.indexOf(UTC_MINUS))>0)){
        iso8601string = replaceColon(iso8601string, iso8601string.indexOf(UTC_MINUS));
        iso8601string = appendZeros(iso8601string, iso8601string.indexOf(UTC_MINUS), UTC_MINUS);
    }

    Date date = null;
    if(iso8601string.contains(":"))
        date = DATE_FORMAT_1.parse(iso8601string);
    else{
        date = DATE_FORMAT_2.parse(iso8601string);
    }
    return date;
}

public static String toISO8601String(Date date){
    return DATE_FORMAT_1.format(date);
}

private static String replaceColon(String sourceStr, int offsetIndex){
    if(sourceStr.substring(offsetIndex).contains(":"))
        return sourceStr.substring(0, offsetIndex) + sourceStr.substring(offsetIndex).replace(":", "");
    return sourceStr;
}

private static String appendZeros(String sourceStr, int offsetIndex, String offsetChar){
    if((sourceStr.length()-1)-sourceStr.indexOf(offsetChar,offsetIndex)<=2)
        return sourceStr + "00";
    return sourceStr;
}
```

}

Comment: Watch out -- DateFormat and derived classes are not multithread compatible! Using static SimpleDateFormat objects such as DATE_FORMAT_1 and DATE_FORMAT_2 means that multiple threads calling the ISO8601DateFormatter functions will share the same DateFormat object. This leads to data corruption and incorrect dates being returned from the DateFormat calls. To fix this, you should just make the pattern strings constants and create local SimpleDateFormat variables whenever needed. This will ensure that each object is just used by one thread.

Comment: A better fix for thread-safety is to instead use a date-time library built for thread-safety. In Java that world be either Joda-Time or java.time.

Answer (score -2):

I think what a lot of people want to do is parse JSON date strings. There is a good chance if you come to this page that you might want to convert a JavaScript JSON date to a Java date.

To show what a JSON date string looks like:

```
    var d=new Date();
    var s = JSON.stringify(d);

    document.write(s);
    document.write("<br />"+d);


    "2013-12-14T01:55:33.412Z"
    Fri Dec 13 2013 17:55:33 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

The JSON date string is 2013-12-14T01:55:33.412Z.

Dates are not covered by JSON spec per say, but the above is a very specific ISO 8601 format, while ISO_8601 is much much bigger and that is a mere subset albeit a very important one.

See http://www.json.org
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601
See http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

As it happens I wrote a JSON parser and a PLIST parser both of which use ISO-8601 but not the same bits.

```
/*
    var d=new Date();
    var s = JSON.stringify(d);

    document.write(s);
    document.write("<br />"+d);


    "2013-12-14T01:55:33.412Z"
    Fri Dec 13 2013 17:55:33 GMT-0800 (PST)


 */
@Test
public void jsonJavaScriptDate() {
    String test =  "2013-12-14T01:55:33.412Z";

    Date date = Dates.fromJsonDate ( test );
    Date date2 = Dates.fromJsonDate_ ( test );

    assertEquals(date2.toString (), "" + date);

    puts (date);
}
```

I wrote two ways to do this for my project. One standard, one fast.

Again, JSON date string is a very specific implementation of ISO 8601....

(I posted the other one in the other answer which should work for PLIST dates, which are a different ISO 8601 format).

The JSON date is as follows:

```
public static Date fromJsonDate_( String string ) {

    try {

        return new SimpleDateFormat ( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX").parse ( string );
    } catch ( ParseException e ) {
        return Exceptions.handle (Date.class, "Not a valid JSON date", e);
    }


}
```

PLIST files (ASCII non GNUNext) also uses ISO 8601 but no miliseconds so... not all ISO-8601 dates are the same. (At least I have not found one that uses milis yet and the parser I have seen skip the timezone altogether OMG).

Now for the fast version (you can find it in Boon).

```
public static Date fromJsonDate( String string ) {

    return fromJsonDate ( Reflection.toCharArray ( string ), 0, string.length () );

}
```

Note that Reflection.toCharArray uses unsafe if available but defaults to string.toCharArray if not.

(You can take it out of the example by replacing Reflection.toCharArray ( string ) with string.toCharArray()).

```
public static Date fromJsonDate( char[] charArray, int from, int to ) {

    if (isJsonDate ( charArray, from, to )) {
        int year = CharScanner.parseIntFromTo ( charArray, from + 0, from + 4 );
        int month = CharScanner.parseIntFromTo ( charArray,  from +5,  from +7 );
        int day = CharScanner.parseIntFromTo ( charArray,  from +8,  from +10 );
        int hour = CharScanner.parseIntFromTo ( charArray,  from +11,  from +13 );

        int minute = CharScanner.parseIntFromTo ( charArray,  from +14,  from +16 );

        int second = CharScanner.parseIntFromTo ( charArray,  from +17,  from +19 );

        int miliseconds = CharScanner.parseIntFromTo ( charArray,  from +20,  from +23 );

        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone ( "GMT" );


        return toDate ( tz, year, month, day, hour, minute, second, miliseconds );

    }   else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

The isJsonDate is implemented as follows:

```
public static boolean isJsonDate( char[] charArray, int start, int to ) {
    boolean valid = true;
    final int length = to -start;

    if (length != JSON_TIME_LENGTH) {
        return false;
    }

    valid &=  (charArray [ start + 19 ]  == '.');

    if (!valid) {
        return false;
    }


    valid &=  (charArray[  start +4 ]  == '-') &&
            (charArray[  start +7 ]  == '-') &&
            (charArray[  start +10 ] == 'T') &&
            (charArray[  start +13 ] == ':') &&
            (charArray[  start +16 ] == ':');

    return valid;
}
```

Anyway... my guess is that quite a few people who come here.. might be looking for the JSON Date String and although it is an ISO-8601 date, it is a very specific one that needs a very specific parse.

```
public static int parseIntFromTo ( char[] digitChars, int offset, int to ) {
    int num = digitChars[ offset ] - '0';
    if ( ++offset < to ) {
        num = ( num * 10 ) + ( digitChars[ offset ] - '0' );
        if ( ++offset < to ) {
            num = ( num * 10 ) + ( digitChars[ offset ] - '0' );
            if ( ++offset < to ) {
                num = ( num * 10 ) + ( digitChars[ offset ] - '0' );
                if ( ++offset < to ) {
                    num = ( num * 10 ) + ( digitChars[ offset ] - '0' );
                    if ( ++offset < to ) {
                        num = ( num * 10 ) + ( digitChars[ offset ] - '0' );
                        if ( ++offset < to ) {
                            num = ( num * 10 ) + ( digitChars[ offset ] - '0' );
                            if ( ++offset < to ) {
                                num = ( num * 10 ) + ( digitChars[ offset ] - '0' );
                                if ( ++offset < to ) {
                                    num = ( num * 10 ) + ( digitChars[ offset ] - '0' );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

See https://github.com/RichardHightower/boon
Boon has a PLIST parser (ASCII) and a JSON parser.

The JSON parser is the fastest Java JSON parser that I know of.

Independently verified by the Gatling Performance dudes.

https://github.com/gatling/json-parsers-benchmark

```
Benchmark                               Mode Thr     Count  Sec         Mean   Mean error        Units
BoonCharArrayBenchmark.roundRobin      thrpt  16        10    1   724815,875    54339,825    ops/s
JacksonObjectBenchmark.roundRobin      thrpt  16        10    1   580014,875   145097,700    ops/s
JsonSmartBytesBenchmark.roundRobin     thrpt  16        10    1   575548,435    64202,618    ops/s
JsonSmartStringBenchmark.roundRobin    thrpt  16        10    1   541212,220    45144,815    ops/s
GSONStringBenchmark.roundRobin         thrpt  16        10    1   522947,175    65572,427    ops/s
BoonDirectBytesBenchmark.roundRobin    thrpt  16        10    1   521528,912    41366,197    ops/s
JacksonASTBenchmark.roundRobin         thrpt  16        10    1   512564,205   300704,545    ops/s
GSONReaderBenchmark.roundRobin         thrpt  16        10    1   446322,220    41327,496    ops/s
JsonSmartStreamBenchmark.roundRobin    thrpt  16        10    1   276399,298   130055,340    ops/s
JsonSmartReaderBenchmark.roundRobin    thrpt  16        10    1    86789,825    17690,031    ops/s
```

It has the fastest JSON parser for streams, readers, bytes[], char[], CharSequence (StringBuilder, CharacterBuffer), and String.

See more benchmarks at:

https://github.com/RichardHightower/json-parsers-benchmark

Comment: This Answer about JSON is off-topic from the Question. Furthermore, this Question is incorrect as there is no such thing as a “JSON date” amongst the very few [JSON data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example). And nowadays, all this code can be replaced with a single-line call to built-in Java feature: `Instant.parse( "2013-12-14T01:55:33.412Z" )`