# Formatting the DATE in JSON response

Tags: java, json

I am getting date as below in json response .

```
{"dateTime":"2012-03-03T10:00:00.890+05:30"}
```

I wated to display it like 3 march 2012 10Am in java . How to format this date

Comment: Depends on the platform you are using to parse the JSON object. For example, in PHP you can use the date() function: http://php.net/strtodate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in **Java**, Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) like this:

**EDIT:**
To match with your scenario I have edited it as follows:

```
String input = "2012-03-03T10:00:00.890+05:30";
```

In the above `input` string you will have to remove the `: colon` from the time zone part i.e. `+05:30`. You could use regex to do this as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554852/parsing-a-date-string-using-java-text-simpledateformat). And then use following code to convert it in your format:

```
DateFormat oldFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
DateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMM yyyy hha");

String dateStr = newFormat.format(oldFormat.parse(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS,this date is in standart format so new date(object.dateTime) will parse your date. Then by using toGMTString or toLocalString you will have the right format. 
You just have to strip the 4 first and 4 last characters of the string returned.

Answer (score 0):

what language are you using to display the date?

You would have to parse the value as a date, then you can change the format of the display of that date.

Comment: Sorry. forgot to mention it .In java language

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Kuldeep Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9515464/642706) is correct. But using the java.util.Date/Calendar classes should be avoided as they are badly designed and implemented.

Instead use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), or in Java 8, the new java.time.* classes (inspired by Joda-Time).

While Joda-Time allows you to define your own [specific formats](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for parsing, in your case you needn't. The constructors on Joda-Time's [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class are already built to parse the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format you are using.

Example code…

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTimeZone timeZone_Kolkata = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );

String input = "2012-03-03T10:00:00.890+05:30";
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( input );
DateTime dateTimeInUtc = dateTime.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime dateTimeInKolkata = dateTime.toDateTime( timeZone_Kolkata );

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forStyle("LS").withLocale( new Locale( "en", "IN" ) ); // English, India.
String output = formatter.print( dateTime );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "dateTimeInUtc: " + dateTimeInUtc );
System.out.println( "dateTimeInKolkata: " + dateTimeInKolkata );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2012-03-02T20:30:00.890-08:00
dateTimeInUtc: 2012-03-03T04:30:00.890Z
dateTimeInKolkata: 2012-03-03T10:00:00.890+05:30
output: 2 March, 2012 8:30 PM
```